# "Iterate" a function's return values

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function which consults some external stateful service and returns a value from it, for simplicity let's assume the value is an integer:

```
i = 10
def foo():
    global i
    i -= 1
    return i
```

It's clear that I can call this function 9 times before it returns a falsy value (the 10th call will return 0 which will evaluate to false in boolean contexts). With some function that works this way, I can now "iterate" it by wrapping it in a generator:

```
def take_while_truthy(func):
    while True:
        nextval = func()
        if not nextval: 
            break
        yield nextval
```

And then:

```
for x in take_while_truthy(foo):
    print x
```

gives me:

```
9
8
[...]
2
1
```

My question is: is there a higher-order function somewhere in the standard library which does this or something like it? I skimmed [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) and [functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) but didn't find anything quite like what I want to do. Have I missed something?

Comment: `itertools.takewhile` comes closest, but for that, you have to change your function to a generator or wrap it in a generator.

Comment: What's wrong with http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile ?  Are you looking for `bool` as the predicate?

Comment: `takewhile` needs an iterable -- in my case the function returns a scalar value and is not a generator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can actually be done using the built-in [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter), if you provide two arguments instead of one then the first is expected to be a function that will be called repeatedly until the return value of the function reaches the sentinel value:

```
for x in iter(foo, 0):
    print x
```

Here is what the itertools solution might look like, `iter()` is definitely cleaner but this allows you to test for any falsy return:

```
from itertools import takewhile, imap, repeat
for x in takewhile(bool, imap(lambda f: f(), repeat(foo))):
    print x
```

Comment: success! it would be nice if the second argument could be a predicate, so then any falsy value could stop the iteration, but this'll do nicely.